# When I run my app on Android Studio, emulator starts but it says that the test app crashed

Tags: java, android, crash

I am trying to create a sign in sign up page. I have 3 pages ( activities). All I do is click a sign up or sign in button on main activity and it takes me to other pages.

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.appt.shreyabisht.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


Button btn_sign;
Button btn_sign_up;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn_sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign);
    btn_sign.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);
    btn_sign_up.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void btclick() {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.appt.shreyabisht.second"));
}

private void btsignclick() {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.appt.shreyabisht.third"));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_sign:
            btclick();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_sign_up:
            btsignclick();
            break;
    }

}
}
```

I am not sure how multiple buttons work and if I should create a separate  `public void onClick(View view)` for another button.  Please suggest.

When I run the app, the error I get is :

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appt.shreyabisht.test, PID: 832
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com.appt.shreyabisht.test/com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity}
Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
```

(There are more lines but I think this is the one causing the crash)

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:gravity="center|bottom"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/backw"
android:weightSum="1">




<Button
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign in"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="@string/App_name"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sign_up_btn"
    android:id="@+id/sign_up"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.second"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.second" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.test.third"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.appt.shreyabisht.third" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml` file please.

Comment: has @MohammadRahchamani says, post your xml (to see how you have defined the buttons) and if is possible the xml of the manifest, to see if you have defined the other activities.

Comment: You have created your MainActivity in the "test" package 'com.appt.shreyabisht.test'. Move it out there. On up. Test-Package is still there for tests and not implementation

Comment: posting main_activity.xml

Comment: @stefan : I created 2 activities first and it worked in the test package. I just added more buttons and a new activity and it gives me this error this time.

Comment: @mohammad: as you asked, I have uploaded both the files. Please let me know what im doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here :

```
btn_sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);
```

you are trying to find a view by id = `btn_sign_up` but you are defining it by another id here :

```
android:id="@+id/sign_up"
```

Comment: i cant thank you enough. Although i have a question, i was under the impression that if some ids were wrong, the button would not work . but in this case the app crashed every time i tried to run it. Is that how it works? If there is one id mismatch the app crashes?

Comment: @shrbisht , yes  when you add a new widget (buttons, edit text, etc) and you want to use it in you activity, first of all, the layout must be charged before you can bind it. And the binding `btn_sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up)` must be done always if you want to use the widget. If you don't do it, the app try to search the functionality and never will know it because doesn't have any reference to the widget.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Thank you for the explanation. I tried incorporating expandable view in my test app today and ive rechecked the code twice, i cant find why its crashing again. Can you help me with that ? I can post the files if you care to have a look. Thanks